# Buttons in ScrollView not enabled

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uibutton, uipagecontrol

Using Erica Sadun's scroll view example I created a project.
I now have a scroll view and a page control in my project.
I create a new view for each page and add it to my scroll view as seen below.
Each view has 5 buttons so I can scroll 5 by 5.
However the buttons do not seem to be enabled.
Any ideas why?

```
    // Create the scroll view and set its content size and delegate
    sv = [[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f)] autorelease];
    sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(NPAGES * 300.0f, sv.frame.size.height);
    sv.pagingEnabled = YES;
    sv.delegate = self;


    // Load in all the pages
    for (int i = 0; i < NPAGES; i++)
    {
        UIView *menuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f)];


    for (int j = 0; j < 5 * (i+1); j++)
        {
            UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuimage.png"];
            UIImage *menuImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuimageselected.png"];
UIButton *menuButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];

            menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(j * 60.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 60.0f);
            [menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(menuButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        menuButton.tag = j + 5 * i;

            menuButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            [menuButton setImage:menuImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [menuButton setImage:menuImage2 forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [menuButton setImage:menuImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
            [menuButton setEnabled:YES];


            [menuImage release];
            [menuButton release];
            [menuView addSubview:menuButton];

        }

        [sv addSubview:menuView];
        [sv bringSubviewToFront:menuView];

        [menuView release];

    }

    [self.view addSubview:sv];
```

Comment: How do u say that they are not enabled?

Comment: Here, You have not implemented any selector so how can you say that button is not enabled? And again please elaborate what actually you want to do.

Comment: there are so many errors in this code  1.never try to retain a button 2.I dont think so you will get any thing on your second page because your menuView.frame.origin.x is always 0 3. you need to add target for your button touch event

Comment: @7KV7: by not enabled i mean the image doesn't change when i touch the button.

Comment: @rptwsthi: i implemented the selector now. it still doesn't work. but even if i hadn't implemented the selector it should have still highlighted when i touched it. the action taken is not related with how it looks. since it is a button, it should already have the functionality to highlight when i touch. right?

Comment: @Amit Singh: no i already get all my pages loaded with the images. of course i didn't paste my full code here so you might think there are errors :] what is wrong with retaining a button?

Comment: Ok everyone, thank you for trying to answer my question but let's make this clear, it's not related with the extra methods of UIButton. Anything that is a UIButton will already implement highlighting and whatnot. The problem is -as far as I see- the touch functionality is not working because of scroll view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing the frame of the view I am adding to my scroll view.
So instead of this line:

```
UIView *menuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f)];
```

I now make the view change its frame every time I change the page:

```
UIView *menuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 300.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f)];
```

So the reason was related with the location of the frame of the view  I was adding to the scroll view. This problem seems to occur when scroll view is used together with paging. When the page changes make sure the view inside scrollview also moves to the same frame.

Answer (score 1):

To change image on touch use

```
[menuButton setImage:menuImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Also make sure you have `menubutton.showTouchOnHighlight = YES;` and

```
menuButton.adjustImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Maybe the scrollView takes the touch events. Try these

```
scrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
scrollView.canCancelContentTouches = NO;
```

Comment: sorry but even if you don't add a separate image for highlight or enable, the buttons come with one by default.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
for (int i = 0; i < NPAGES; i++)
{
    UIView *menuView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 300.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 60.0f)] autorelease];

    for (j = 0; j < 5 ; j++)
    {
        UIImage *menuImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuimage.png"];
        UIImage *menuImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuimageselected.png"];
        UIButton *menuButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        menuButton.frame = CGRectMake(j * 60.0f, 0.0f, 60.0f, 60.0f);
        menuButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [menuButton setImage:menuImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [menuButton setImage:menuImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [menuButton setEnabled:YES];
        [menuButton addTarget:self action:@selector(someSelector)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [menuView addSubview:menuButton];
    }

    [sv addSubview:menuView];
}
```

and please verify that the two images named `menuimage.png`  and  `menuimageselected.png` are there.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't do anything about the button working. it only changes where the buttons will be. this is not related with my question

Comment: the same code is working fine with me its verified jsut by changing the two images

Comment: try this [menuButton setImage:menuImage2 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

Answer (score 0):

Please Implement this code inside your scrollView

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(X, Y, Width, Height);
    btn.tag = //your tag Number;
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(showGameDetail:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And Add this method

```
 -(IBAction)showGameDetail:(id)sender
 {
    //Your Code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [menuImage release];
```

`menuImage` should not be release. It is come from `[UIImage imageNamed:], and it is an autoreleased object. It will cause the image over released.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this and i am not sure whether it works out in your case.

```
 [scrollView bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would declare "J" inside the "for" parentheses.
2. You are retaining the UIButton and then releasing it. You don't need to do either, because you aren't allocating it.
3. You shouldn't release "menuImage".
4. You are assigning "menuImage2" to selected state of the UIButton. It should be UIControlStateHighlighted.

Edit:

Dont do this:

```
 [menuImage release];
 [menuButton release];
```

Also try this:

```
- (void) menuButtonClicked: (id) sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"clicked %d",[btn tag]);
}
```

Comment: See the code I updated, these don't really matter in button not reacting to touches..

Comment: Actually it matters. try "for (int j = 0; j < 5 * (i+1); j++)" and see for yourself.

Comment: I see. But still it doesn't work for all the buttons. but only for the ones on the first page. when you add these lines in the menuButtonClicked function you will see. - (IBAction) menuButtonClicked: (id) sender
{
 UIButton *btn = sender;
 NSLog(@"clicked %d",[sender tag]);
}

Comment: also should change the tag like this: 
   menuButton.tag = j + 5 * i;

Comment: Can you update your post with the new code. I thought you were using selector. try -(void)menuButtonClicked:(id)sender not IBAction since you are creating the buttons at runtime.

Comment: i updated but it also doesnt matter because you can also call ibactions manually.

Comment: I think the problem is related with the frames of my menuView and scroll view.

Comment: when i am changing the page to second page, the frame of menuView stays at the back and does not respond to touches